# POSIX Yacc does not support

Tags: makefile, compilation, posix, bison, yacc

I have this makefile:

```
CC = gcc
CFLAGS = -Wall -Wno-yacc
BISON = /usr/bin/bison

OBJ = pasc200.tab.c lex.yy.c hashtbl.o semantic.o types.o ast.o

pasc200: lex.yy.c pasc200.tab.c pasc200.tab.h hashtbl.o semantic.o types.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) $(OBJ) -o $@ -lm

pasc200.tab.c pasc200.tab.h: pasc200.y semantic.o types.o ast.o
    @echo "Running Bison: $(BISON)"
    $(BISON) -v -d pasc200.y

lex.yy.c: pasc200.l pasc200.tab.h semantic.o types.o
    flex pasc200.l

semantic.o: types.h hashtbl.h semantic.c semantic.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o semantic.o -g -c semantic.c

hashtbl.o: types.h hashtbl.c hashtbl.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o hashtbl.o -g -c hashtbl.c

types.o: hashtbl.h types.c types.h
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o types.o -g -c types.c

ast.o: ast.h ast.c types.h types.o
    $(CC) $(CFLAGS) -o ast.o -g -c ast.c

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f *.o
    rm -f *.tab.*
    rm -f *.yy.c
    rm -f *.output
```

When I try to run the makefile (`make pasc200`) it always shows that there are warnings on my code like:

```
pasc200.y:23.1-7: warning: POSIX Yacc does not support %define [-Wyacc]
   23 | %define parse.error verbose
      | ^~~~~~~

pasc200.y:148.2-7: warning: POSIX Yacc does not support %empty [-Wyacc]
  148 | |%empty ;                               ...
      |  ^~~~~~
```

... and so on.

I tried to run it like this:
`/usr/bin/bison pasc200.y`
and it doesn't show the warnings but in the makefile it doesn't work. (I have also tried in the makefile to change it to `$(BISON) pasc200.y` still doesn't work.)

Comment: You didn't show us what make printed before the error messages you see.  What command did make run?

Comment: Also, I don't know what it means to add `-Wno-yacc` to the GCC compile line.  There's no such warning option in GCC as far as I know.

Comment: Just wanted to say that this rule: `pasc200.tab.c pasc200.tab.h: pasc200.y ...` does not mean what you probably think it means.  It doesn't mean "once invocation of that recipe will build both files".  It means, "run this recipe once for each file that needs to be updated".  If you don't use `-j` it won't matter since the when make checks if the second file needs to be updated, it won't need to be since you just did it.  But if you run with `-j` you can easily get two instances of Bison running on the same target which would be bad.  That's not the problem you show here but it can happen.

Comment: The direct-execution `bison` command you present does not correspond to the `bison` command you are running via your makefile.  You use extra options in the makefile recipe, which seems likely to explain why `bison` warns in one case but not the other.

Comment: Supposing that you do not want warnings about your input's incompatibilities with `yacc`, you should be able to suppress them by adding `-Wno-yacc` to your *`bison`* command (not your C compilation commands).